# Shell doesn't display input characters after "tail -f"

Tags: bash, display, tail

I use "tail -f" to monitor log files. After interrupted by ctrl-c, the shell doesn't display my input chars from keyboard any more. Something like

```
terminal> tail -f /log/a.log
then ctrl-c
terminal>
```

No matter what I input, it doesn't display it. But after hitting "enter", it will get run my input command if no typo (unseen).

Seem it's a shell setting problem.

Comment: The `reset` command will sort this out for you.

Comment: Is Ctrl + C taking tail to background? try the command fg to get it back if that is the case

Answer (score 0):

with gnu tail, the -f does not play any sort of cursor games (i.e. ncurses library routine) so you shouldn't ever have that problem.

1) try interrupting with ctrl-z and seei if the problem still shows up

2) try running with the -q flag as well